# Как задать разные действия программы при запуске после установки и при обычном запуске?

Tags: c++, установка, inno-setup, админка, запуск

У программы есть определенное поведение при любом запуске. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы после переустановки или обновления это поведение было другим, не таким, как при обычном запуске (если между текущим запуском и обновлением/переустановкой были еще запуски). Обновление в данном случае - это запуск установочника на компьютере, на котором уже установлена программа.

У меня было такое решение добавить в установщик программы файл-болванку, которая будет распаковываться в папку с программой.
При запуске программа проверяет наличие этого файла. Если он есть, то она выполняет действия, необходимые после обновления/переустановки, а затем удаляет файл-болванку.
Таким образом, при следующем запуске программа не найдет этот файл, и по этому признаку поймёт, что её уже запускали, и будет действовать в обычном режиме.

Но это не работает - всё дело в правах администратора. Программу устанавливает администратор компьютера, а с ней работает обычный пользователь, поэтому установленная программа уже прав админа не имеет. Получается, установщик, имея права админа, может создать в папке с программой этот файлик. А вот программа удалить его не может, так как установлена в папку Program Files, куда имеет доступ только админ.

За то программа может работать с файлами данного пользователя. И казалось бы, можно создавать этот файл в Appdat'e установочником, а потом программой его удалять. Однако установочник не имеет доступа к папкам пользователя, и всё делает только с папками админа.

При том, нельзя заранее определить, для какого юзера будет ставиться программа. Это означает, что установочнику нельзя задать абсолютный путь к Appdat'e.

Какие еще есть способы заставить программу после установки/обновления делать не те же действия, как при обычном запуске.

Программа написана на Qt. Используемый установочник Inno Setup Compiller. ОС Windows 10.

Comment: Метку установочника добавил

Comment: *"Однако установочник не имеет доступа к папкам пользователя, и всё делает только с папками админа."* - ничего подобного, можно без проблем добавлять в Appdat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько способов решить Вашу проблему,  но только Вы знаете, как будет лучше.

Самое первое - у Inno Setup есть такая штука как [postinstall](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=postinstall) - после удачной инсталляции можно запустить свою программу с параметрами.

Второе. Есть есть [C:\ProgramData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-folderlocations-programdata). Как там написано

> ProgramData specifies the path to the program-data folder (normally C:\ProgramData). Unlike the Program Files folder, this folder can be used by applications to store data for standard users, because it does not require elevated permissions.

Вольный перевод

> ProgramData - это такая папка для данных программы (обычно в C:\ProgramData). В противоположность Program Files, эта папка может использоваться приложениями для сохранения данных для "стандартного пользователя", так как она не требует повышения привилегий.

Также, никто не отменял реестр.

Comment: Насчёт ProgramData могу сказать следующее. Проверил уже этот вариант, и вот что выяснил. В Qt есть класс, отвечающий за пути - QStandardPaths, и он не имеет доступ к ProgramData. Это является багом Qt, и описано тут: https://bugreports.qt.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/QTBUG-44348 и тут: https://bugreports.qt.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/QTBUG-40565

Comment: Порыл ещё. Оказывается, можно получить путь ProgramData. Описано тут: https://forum.qt.io/topic/103227/how-to-get-windows-programdata-location/4

Answer (score 2):

пример добавления файла в AppData

```
[Files]
Source: "ExampleFile.txt"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\ProgName"
```

А можно добавлять файл и в Program Files, но переделать приложение чтобы оно сравнивало его с тем, что лежит в AppData.

Comment: Установочник действительно может добавлять файлы в Appdat'у, однако это работает только в Windows 7. На десятке тот же самый установочник ничего не добавит.

Comment: А вот со сравнением это круто придумано, я не додумался. Программа не может редактировать собственные файлы, но может их читать.

Comment: @СергейМалышев *"На десятке тот же самый установочник ничего не добавит. "* - с чего бы это?

Comment: Этого я не знаю, но такова реальность. То, что работает на семёрке, не работает на десятке.

Comment: @СергейМалышев Это все работает на 10 без проблем.